# Universal style editor for IDE themes

Tags: visual-studio, ide, notepad++, editor, vi

A few days ago I saw an article somewhere mentioning there was a program or plugin that allowed you to define a color theme in a common format that can be shared across different IDEs (some had support built in and others needed a plugin to process the theme).

An example of a theme I'd like to customize once and use everywhere is [Monokai](https://atom.io/themes/monokai)

For the life of me, I cannot find the article and after crawling through multiple permutations in Google I decided to ask here.

Thank you so much!

Comment: If you're going to use it for multiple IDE's and some of them will require an additional plugin, wouldn't it be easier and faster to just google  "[IDE] Monakai" for each of them and just install it that way?

Comment: I just used Monokai as an example to point to what I was looking to do. Some IDEs call themes "appearances", others call them styles, other call them syntax highlighting plugins.

In reality, I don't actually want Monokai, it was just an example.

Comment: What I mean is, if it's going to require you to lookup how to install the plugins to access the colourscheme / theme / style / appearance on a case-by-case basis even when you have this "universal style", would it not be easier and faster to just install the styles on a case by case basis?

Comment: It might be easier, but the complexity increases with the number of IDEs and editors in use. Additionally, I would have to lookup and learn the syntax for themes for each environment. I use about 6 different ones regularly. The project I'm thinking of does all of this for you. It provides the plugins and certain IDEs like JetBrains and Visual Studio have support built right in.

Comment: if you do find it, please @ me in the answer or a comment, I'd love to know about it.